latest RenderMan Pro Server 26.1 has missing features
In trying to rendering many .rib files
using prman example.rib, gives the following warnings:
R10003 {WARNING} RiLightSource unimplemented. Shader distantlight ignored.
R20108 {WARNING} Color is unimplemented.
R10003 {WARNING} RiSurface unimplemented. Shader plastic ignored.
R20007 {WARNING} Object (null) has unknown displacementbound space shader.

the sphere should be orange color, is renderman crippled?
